# High availability on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, high-availability

I've seen several status updates on Bluemix saying that applications are being restarted and there will be issues logging in, e.g.

> During this time, you might experience temporary errors logging into
>   Bluemix or managing applications, such as starting, staging, and so
>   on. If this situation occurs, retry the operation later. The latest
>   status will be available at http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus throughout
>   the upgrade process.
>
> Existing applications will see a brief restart of instances, but near
>   continuous availability is expected.

Is it possible then to build a high-availability application on Bluemix?

Comment: How do you define "high availability"?

Comment: I would define it as there always being a server that traffic can be successfully routed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IBM Bluemix supports deploying applications in [multiple different regions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/enablingwithbluemix/entry/regions_in_bluemix?lang=en).

Minimising downtime during platform issues can be achieved by hosting your application in multiple regions simultaneously and using an external load-balancer to move traffic between the instances depending on availability.

Replicating application data between regions will be dependent on the individual services you're using. For example, Cloudant supports [multi-master replication](https://cloudant.com/product/cloudant-features/replication/), allowing you to failover without any manual intervention.

Comment: Thanks.  Disappointing though that there's not a way to do it within Bluemix itself like most other PaaS providers.

Comment: In addition to James' answer -- it's important to distinguish between application runtime disruption and application management disruption.  The referenced notification speaks to potential issues managing apps (push, start, stop, restage, etc.).  This is different than having your app unavailable to users (high-availability).  To protect your app from "a brief restart of instances", it is advisable to run at least 3 instances of your app.  It then becomes extremely unlikely that all 3 of your app instances will be running on VMs that are being restarted simultaneously.

Comment: My reason for mentioning the management disruption in relation to high availability is that it makes it difficult to determine if there are failures and recovering from them.